# Resposta do PHP Excel em JSON

Tags: php, json, phpexcel

Estou tentando obter uma resposta para saber se o arquivo do [PHPExcel](http://www.voltsdigital.com.br/labs/gerando-planilhas-excel-com-php/) já baixou, para então prosseguir com meu algoritmo.

Eu tentei colocar no meu arquivo phpexcel a seguinte linha antes do exit;

```
echo json_encode(array("teste" => 1));
```

Porém não funciona. Ele retorna como não definido

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'post',
  url  : 'services/'+url,
  data : {
     data : competencia
 },
 success: function (data) {
   if(data.teste === 1)
    alert('baixou');
   else
     alert('nao baixou: '+data.teste);
   }
});
```

Comment: Em vez de `echo`, tente um `die(json_encode(array("teste" => 1)));` e me informe o que aconteceu.

Comment: mas tiro o exit que tem no final?

Comment: die vai parar o processo e retornar o conteúdo que foi colocado dentro. Pode deixar tudo como está e só fazer a alteração;

Comment: ele demorou e retornou não definido

Comment: Bem, vamos ao proximo e ultimo teste,tente executar esse codigo, `$.ajax({
  type : 'post',
  url  : 'services/'+url,
  datatype: 'json',
  data : {
     data : competencia
 },
 success: function (data) {
   if(data.teste === 1)
    alert('baixou');
   else
     alert('nao baixou: '+data.teste);
   }
});`

Comment: Nada. Agora nem alert exibe mais. Mas valeu a intenção de ajudar

Comment: `var form = $('<form action="services/'+url+'" method="post" >'+
                        '<input type="hidden" value="'+competencia+'" name="data" />'+
                        '</form>');
                    $('body').append(form);
                    form.submit()` se eu colocar esse comando funciona, mas não tenho como saber o retorno no jquery

Comment: eu gostaria de que só atualizasse a pagina depois que baixasse

Answer (score 0):

Faça um parse dos dados retornados, assim você terá um objeto.

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'post',
  url  : 'services/'+url,
  data : {
     data : competencia
 },
 success: function (data) {
   //Parse do JSON retornado
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);

   if(obj.teste === 1)
    alert('baixou');
   else
     alert('nao baixou: '+data.teste);
   }
});
```